# Determine the linter used in VSCode for CSS and other languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you determine the linter used in VSCode for CSS and other languages?

---

Here are some extra info asked by @starball.

- Full message copied to clipboard:

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/nico/kdnicomac/programmation/javascript/centered_polygonal_number_generator/centered_polygonal_number_generator.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "unknownProperties",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Unknown property: 'dominant-baseline'",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 183,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 183,
    "endColumn": 34
}]
```

- Screenshots

[image: CSS lint — Problem console table mode]

[image: CSS lint — Problem console tree mode]

Comment: extension providing a diagnostic can be found in the problems panel. can even copy JSON with right click -> "Copy".

Comment: Curiously, the diagnostics you refer to do not specify the name of the linters that generated them. And that’s what I want to know.

Comment: please give the following: screenshot your problems panel- both in tree mode and in table mode (two screenshots), and right click the diagnostic entry and click copy and paste the contents into your question post in a code block.